# summary of the algorithm of K sum

Tags: algorithm

It is the well-konw `Twelvefold way`:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way

Where we want to find the number of solutions for following equation:

```
X1 + X2 + ... + XK = target
```

from the given array:

```
vector<int> vec(N);
```

We can assume vec[i] > 0. There are 3 cases, for example

```
vec = {1,2,3}, target = 5, K = 3.
```

1. Xi can be duplicate and solution can be duplicate.

   6 solutions are {1,2,2}, {2,1,2}, {2,2,1}, {1,1,3}, {1,3,1}, {3,1,1}
2. Xi can be duplicate and solution cannot be duplicate.

   2 solutions are {1,2,2}, {1,1,3}
3. Xi cannot be duplicate and solution cannot be duplicate.

   0 solution.

The ides must be using dynamic programming:

```
dp[i][k], the number of solution of target = i, K = k.
```

And the iteration relation is :

```
if(i > num[n-1]) dp[i][k] += dp[i-num[n-1]][k-1];
```

For three cases, they depend on the runing order of i,n,k. I know the result when there is no restriction of K (sum of any number of variables):

case 1:

```
int KSum(vector<int>& vec, int target) {
    vector<int> dp(target + 1);
    dp[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= target; ++i)
        for (int n = 0; n < vec.size(); n++)
            if (i >= vec[n]) dp[i] += dp[i - vec[n]];

    return dp.back();
}
```

case 2:

```
for (int n = 0; n < vec.size(); n++)
    for (int i = 1; i <= target; ++i)
```

case 3:

```
for (int n = 0; n < vec.size(); n++)
    for (int i = target; i >= 1; --i)
```

When there is additional variable k, do we just simply add the for loop

```
for(int k = 1; k <= K; k++)
```

at the outermost layer?

**EDIT:**

I tried case 1，just add for loop of K most inside:

```
int KSum(vector<int> vec, int target, int K) {
    vector<vector<int>> dp(K+1,vector<int>(target + 1,0));
    dp[0][0] = 1;
    for (int n = 0; n < vec.size(); n++)
        for (int i = 1; i <= target; ++i)
            for (int k = 1; k <= K; k++)
            {
                if (i >= vec[n]) dp[k][i] += dp[k - 1][i - vec[n]];
            }

    return dp[K][target];
}
```

Is it true for case 2 and case 3？

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'duplicate' (and possibly give an example for the cases)? It's also not clear how the iteration condition and loops produce the desired answers, could you post the full pseudocode for those?

Comment: @kcsquared pls see my example and the full code without K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution without variable `K` dp[i] represents how many solutions are there to achieve sum `i`.

Including the variable `K` means that we added another dimension to our subproblem. This dimension doesn't necessarily have to be on a specific axis. Your `dp` array could look like `dp[i][k]` or `dp[k][i]`.

- `dp[i][k]` means how many solutions to accumulate sum `i` using `k` numbers (duplicate or unique)
- `dp[k][i]` means using `k` numbers how many solutions to accumulate sum `i`

Both are the same things. Meaning that you can add the loop outside or inside.

Comment: but I tried outermost layer, and got the incorrect result.

Comment: I think by outer I would mean the following sequence: first loop will be the one with target, second one will be for k and third one would be for vec.size()

Comment: This order is true for all three cases, right?

Comment: I would say so. It strictly depends on how you do it.